# c++ : getting a wierd print out

Tags: c++

that's my code:

```
long base2(int number)
{
   long result = 0;
   int num = number;
   int multi = 1;
   int rem;
   while(num > 0)
   {
    rem = num % 2;
    result = result + (rem * multi);
    num = num / 2;
    multi = multi * 10;
   }
   return result;
}
```

I'm getting a weird print: `-1884801888`

I ran the debugger and its calculating properly but just at the end the final answer changes to this `-1884801888`

[The printing happens in the main, I checked, the number changes here to `-1884801888`]

Thank you!

Comment: `multi = multi*10;` Eventually goes out of the `int` range perhaps?

Comment: im new to c++ (came from java), and i know i have to take care of the memory here. but overflow where?! there is no array or somthing i have to take care of... do i have to delete from the memory somthing?

Comment: The code looks correct. How do you call the function and how do you print the result? Also perhaps its integer overflow, if you deal with large numbers...

Comment: @YakirYehuda integer overflow.  You are trying to store a value larger than an integer can hold

Comment: changed to long and still same answer.

Comment: Also try `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: What input are you giving your function?  Have you tried small and simple inputs, such as `0`, `1`, and `8`?   Do those work or fail?

Comment: thank u all i got it! it was int overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most common platforms nowadays, both `int` and `long` are 32 bits wide.  You are causing an *integer overflow*, where the values you're computing exceed the range representable in signed 32-bit integers.

If the values don't fit in 32 bits but do fit in 63 or 64 bits, you can use `long long` or `unsigned long long` (or the fixed-width types `int64_t` or `uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>`) data types to store the result.  If those aren't big enough, then you'll need to use a more complicated solution (e.g. the GMP library has arbitrary-sized integer support), but only do that as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to take a number, and print out its binary representation, by first converting it to a sort of decimal-coded-binary.  There's no need to convert it, the number is already stored as a bunch of 0s and 1s internally.  In fact, printing it out has to go through some processing in order to print it out as a decimal number.

Here's how to print out a number in a few different ways:

```
const int foo = 17;
std::bitset<sizeof(foo)*8> b(foo);

std::cout << "Decimal:  " << foo
          << "\nHex:      " << std::hex << foo
          << "\nOctal:    " << std::oct << foo
          << "\nBinary:   " << b << std::endl;
```

The binary form prints out all the leading zeroes, this way, but there are other ways which skip the leading zeroes.